# Obtengo UnsupportedOperationException al eliminar de un List en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código en Java de Android:

```
List<String> parts = uri.getPathSegments();
parts.remove(parts.size()-1);
```

Me devuelve ese error

> UnsupportedOperationException

He buscado por [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list) el error es porque tiene un tamaño fijo.

Se puede solventar de una manera, se puede alterar el tamaño de un `List`?

Comment: Que es lo que necesitas, quitar el ultimo elemento?

Comment: Si el ultimo elemento que es el nombre del fichero, es decir obtener solo el path de un uri

Comment: Lo he conseguido con parts.toArray(new String[parts.size() -1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor al interactuar con listas externas (p.e. una lista que es el resultado de una operación) que quieres manipular es crear una nueva lista a partir de ella y luego modificarla de acuerdo a tus necesidades. En este caso, sería tan simple como hacer esto:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>(uri.getPathSegments());
//resto de tu código...
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es convertirlo a `Array` modificando su tamaño.

```
List<String> parts = uri.getPathSegments();
parts.toArray(new String[parts.size() -1]);
```